# Export hidden columns to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel

I´m working in Sharepoint Online. Now I export an excel with current items of list and it´s ok, but I want to export all items of list.

How can I do to include hidden columns into index list then export it to excel?

Answer (score 1):

The “Export to Excel” function is used to export all items in the current view. It means, the columns and items in the exported table are determined by the current list view. So before exporting to excel, you should modify the list view to show all columns and items which you want to export to the excel file.

Another method, you can connect SharePoint list as a data source in Excel workbook using the ListData.svc. Using this method, the columns and items in the table are not determined by the list view.

1. Create a excel file in client.
2. Get external data from OData Data Feed.
3. Link to https:///_vti_bin/listdata.svc.
4. Select the lists which you want to display and click Next.
5. Enter the information such as file name for this data connection and click Finish.

If you are working with large list, export a large list to an Excel will let you work with large list without blocking. But if you connect the table to the list (from OData Data Feed) using the listdata web service, it will throw threshold error if the list has more than at 5,000 items.

Note: SharePoint Online uses the Large List Resource Throttling feature. By default, the list view threshold is configured at 5,000 items. When the defined item limit in a list is exceeded, the error message will be displayed. For SharePoint Online, this limit can't be changed.

Information about how to manage large lists/libraries in SPO.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59